# single application in xrdp from windows 7 to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, xrdp

I have my Windows 7 host machine, and Ubuntu Server 14 in Virtual Box like guest machine. Xrdp was installed in the Ubuntu machine. I want to run only one single application when connecting to guest. When specify program path in standart mstsc.exe I got the error. How  I can connect to Ubuntu and run single application?

Thanks!